# docker login with non interactive session returns 401

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry

I have a really strange issue with the non interactive docker login command. I am trying to login to my docker repository using the following command:

```
docker login -u emi -p 123 my.dockerrepo.com:5000
```

This command returns the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://my.dockerrepo.com:5000/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

However, if I run the above command without -p and enter the same password in the shell it works perfectly.

Comment: some kind of special chars in your password?

Comment: Consider using a single quotations. According to the spec it should work but I ran in to the same problem before with docker version 17.03.0-ce  _docker login -u 'emi' -p '123' my.dockerrepo.com:5000_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a single quotations. According to the spec it should work but I ran in to the same problem before with docker version *17.03.0-ce*  `docker login -u 'emi' -p '123' my.dockerrepo.com:5000` would work in your case.